# (Batch File) How to make a batch file read one specific line in a text file

Tags: batch-file, text

I have been trying to make a batch file read one specific line I use this:

```
set "xprvar=" 
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%p in (variables.txt) do (echo %%p)
```

When I use this it dose skip to the 4th line but it also reads the next lines is there any way I can make it just read that one line?

Comment: `... do (echo %%p& goto break)` and put the `:break` label in next line

Comment: @Aacini thank you it works fine now

Comment: @Aacini It was worth a real answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Aacini answered my question but he did it in a comment so I posted this to tell people that there is an answer here.)

```
:Test1
set "xprvar=" for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%p in (variables.txt) do (echo %%p& goto break)

:break
pause
goto END
```

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't get Zones/AAcini answer to work, but based on theirs, the following worked for us:

```
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%L in (changes.txt) do (set "lineWeWant=%%L"& goto break)

:break

echo lineWeWant is [%lineWeWant%]
```